# login page not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hi im trying to make a login page but im not able to run it properly. when i enter username and password it automatically loads back to login page. I have some other problems that i'm not sure it it is checking username and password form database before getting logged in or not and some issues with sessions. I need your help please and here is my code

Model file

login_model.php

```
<?php
class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
    function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('id, username, password');
        $this->db->from('login');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_row()==1)
        {
            return $query->result();
            }

        else
        {
        return false;   
            }
        }   
    }
?>
```

controller file

Login_controller.php

```
<?php
class Login_controller extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct(){
    parent:: __construct();

    }   
    function index()
    {
    $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('Login_view');

        }   
    }
?>
```

Verifylogin_controller.php

```
<?php

     class Verifylogin_controller extends CI_Controller
        {
         public function __construct(){

                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('Login_model',"",TRUE);

                }   
            function index()
            {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');    
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required'); 

            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE )
            {
                $this->load->view('Login_view');
                }
            else
            {
                redirect('Homelogin_controller', 'refresh');
                }

            }

        function check_database($password)
        {
            $username= $this->user->post('username');
            $result = $this->user->login($username, $passwrod);
            if($result)
            {
                $sess_array =array();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    $sess_array =array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'username' =>$row ->username);
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
            }
            return TRUE;
            }
        else
        {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
        return false;   
            }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Homelogin_controller.php

```
<?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
session_start();
} 

class Homelogin_controller extends CI_Controller{
 public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        }
    function index()
{
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))   
    {

        $session_data= $this->session->userdata('logged_In');
        $data['username']= $session_data['username'];
        $this->load->view('Home_view', $data);

        }
else{
    redirect('Login_controller','refresh');
    }

    }   


function logout()
{

    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    session_destroy();
    redirect('Homelogin_controller','refresh');

    }

    }

?>
```

View files
Login_view.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login with codeigniter</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</h1>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php echo form_open('Verifylogin_controller'); ?>
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Home_view.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter - Private Area</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Home</h1>
   <h2>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>!</h2>
   <a href="home/logout">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could do a var_dump($query);exit; after  $query = $this->db->get(); to check if the query is the problem.

Comment: let me try @cjs1978

Comment: @cjs1978 i have tried it.. but doesn't make any difference!! let me explain a bit more. when i press enter after entering username and password the pages and automatically loads back to login page! i don't why it is doing this may be it is not getting username and password from database

Comment: You are loading two different views if login fails. One is in Login_controller and second is in if block of Verify_controller. Since you are using different routes (i.e. different method) for login view and login logic, you would need to redirect to Login_controller if form checking fails. Also, move session managing from callback function to else block of form checking.

Comment: @Tpojka i have checked the code i'm loading the same view in both files

Comment: You should load it only in one view. You can check basic example in [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#form-validation-tutorial) of how it should be managed. Stick with basic example and when you have ti working change some parts one at a time.

Comment: oh ok got it!! thankyou very much @Tpojka